# Is there a way to refresh the page as many times as possible and wait for an element to load in that page in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to check if an element is appearing after refreshing a page continuously, cause it takes a while for the changes to be reflected and the element to appear in that page.

Is there any built in method in selenium using Ruby as the programming language ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, it sounds like the page does not dynamically update once the content is available, so you have to wait until that is true, and then manual refresh, right?

I don't know of anything built into selenium to handle this.  It feels like it might even be a symptom of a UI that needs a little more design work (pardon my critique).  If the user is experiencing the same thing as the test -- kicking off an action, waiting some unspecified period of time, and then manually refreshing to see the results -- that's a kind of lousy user experience.  If that's a bad assumption, and there IS feedback (e.g. a spinner), then your best option will be to conditionally wait for the spinner to appear and then disappear, and then refresh a single time.

If there's really no visible feedback, then you still have a couple of options:

*Easy*: Hardcode a sleep that's longer than the operation will ever take to complete, and refresh once.

*Medium*: In a loop, sleep for a constant delay, refresh, repeat until some timeout.

*Hard*: If the delay required varies widely (sometimes seconds, sometimes minutes), you might consider an exponential back off solution, that sleeps for increasingly longer delays each iteration, before ultimately timing out.  The upside is that you're not frantically refreshing dozens of times, the downside is that your delay might be unnecessarily long, if the content arrives just after the next big delay begins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[wait method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Wait)** for the element to be available.
If you need to refresh the page continuously just make sure to wait after each refresh.